# The POST method is not supported for route Supported methods: GET, HEAD

Tags: php, laravel

I have created a form to save data into my database bt I am getting an unusual erro I tried to search same issue but dose not helped me outwhen I ran command php artisan route:list it showed me GET|HEAD adin/processManager

this is my route

```
Route::post('/admin/processManager',  
    [
        SetupController::class, 'processManager'
    ]
)
```

My Form

```
<form method="POST" action="{{url('admin/processManager')}}">
      {{ csrf_field() }}
      .........
</form>
```

This is my controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\ManagersProcess;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

class SetupController extends Controller {
     public function processManager(Request $request) {
        $data = $request->input();
        try {
            $manager = new ManagersProcess;
            $manager->first_name = $data['first_name'];
            $manager->last_name = $data['last_name'];
            $manager->username = $data['username'];
            $manager->email = $data['email'];
            $manager->phone = $data['phone'];
            $manager->password = md5($data['password']);
            $manager->page_role = $data['page_role'];
            $manager->user_role = $data['user_role'];
            $manager->save();
            return redirect('admin/managers');
        } catch(Exception $e){
            return redirect('admin/managers/create/error');
        }
    }
}
```

Now I am really very unsure what exactly is happening I am using same method do not know wha't s going wrong Please help me out

Comment: You can try add `name` to Route like Route::post(...)->name('route-name'). Then in html you can use `action="{{route('route-name')}}"`

Comment: And btw. You should add full path to controller like `[\App\Http\Controllers\SetupController::class,'processManager']`

Comment: I defined toure name name('admin.processManager') as this and on form i defined the form action as {{route('admin.processManager')}} now I am getting an error as Route [admin.processManager] not defined. have i done somwthing wrong

Comment: Here `Route::post('/admin/processManager',[\App\Http\Controllers\SetupController::class, 'processManager'])->name('admin.processManager');` But check path to controller. Then in html: `<form method="POST" action="{{route('admin.processManager')}}">`

Comment: After follwing your process I am getting this error as Route [admin.processManager] not defined. have I not imported anythign to the applicaiton or notdefined the route

Comment: I think problem is somewhere else. You need to provide more code

Comment: Route for the form Route::get('/admin/managers/{method?}/{id?}', [SetupController::class, 'managers']);

url of the form is localhost/micamp/admin/managers/create

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to add `@method` inside your form :

```
    <form method="POST" action="{{url('admin/processManager')}}">
      @method('GET')

    </form>
```

Based on [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/blade#method-field)

Answer (score -1):

After a long time of headache and searching a lot now it helped me by running simple 2 commands on shell

`php artisan optimize:clear`

`php artisan route:clear`

In short codeigniter is way way far better then Laravel, Laravel is a big headache for me